# Could not make the query numbered : 36 - MySQL Error No : 1059

Tags: mysql, magento, softaculous

I tried to install Magento 1.7.0.2 Version using softaculous, however, it gave the following error :

```
The following errors were found :

Could not make the query numbered : 36
MySQL Error No : 1059
MySQL Error : Identifier name 'UNQ_djfssd_CATRULE_PRD_PRICE_RULE_DATE_WS_ID_CSTR_GROUP_ID_PRD_ID' is too long
```

How do i rectify this ?

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that that identifier is too long:

Here's the maximum size for identifiers (from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html):

```
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|            Identifier            |     Maximum Length (characters)     |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|     Database                     | 64                                  |
|     Table                        | 64                                  |
|     Column                       | 64                                  |
|     Index                        | 64                                  |
|     Constraint                   | 64                                  |
|     Stored Procedure or Function | 64                                  |
|     Trigger                      | 64                                  |
|     View                         | 64                                  |
|     Event                        | 64                                  |
|     Tablespace                   | 64                                  |
|     Server                       | 64                                  |
|     Log File Group               | 64                                  |
|     Alias                        | 256 (see exception following table) |
|     Compound Statement Label     | 16                                  |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

That identifier has 65 characters.

I'm not sure what that means in magento, but it looks very weird to have that as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I'll hazard a guess here that this is identical to the problem with installing later versions of Magento in Softaculous, and a repeat of my answer to the topic at "[Magento Install - Identifier name is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740802/magento-install-identifier-name-is-too-long)":

Late answer, but if anyone else gets this, In Softaculous Advanced settings when installing, check the length of the table prefix, you may find that Softaculous has done something long like "fhfhgsfdg_". Change it to four characters only, i.e. "fhfh_" and you may find it works!

In the original question, the prefix "djfssd_" is the issue, making it "djfs_" would probably have fixed the issue.