# Magento Install - Identifier name is too long

Tags: mysql, magento, softaculous

I am getting this error while trying to install Magento using Softaculous.

```
Could not make the query numbered : 17
MySQL Error No : 1059
MySQL Error : Identifier name 'UNQ_60450534796045053479API2_ACL_RULE_ROLE_ID_RESOURCE_ID_PRIVILEGE' is too long
```

This question has been raised before, but with no answers, just the admonition that mySQL has a limit of 64 characters.

How do I get the installer to use a smaller identifier, or more generally, should I abandon Softaculous and try a manual install?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should! Don't change Magento core functionality. You will have much more problems in the future if You do that.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but if anyone else gets this, In Softaculous Advanced settings when installing, check the length of the table prefix, you may find that Softaculous has done something long like "fhfhgsfdg_". Change it to four characters only, i.e. "fhfh_" and you may find it works!